# How come my computer does not establish an internet connection after restart until I reboot my home router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet

Whenever I shut down my computer and start it back up, an internet connection can't be established on that computer - as if the router doesn't recognise that PC in particular.

To get a working internet connection I have to reboot the router, after which, the previously mentioned PC, will have a working connection.

Although all the other devices in my house *(including wireless)* will successfully request an IP-address and establish a working connection.

---

What I have tried *(doesn't solve the issue)*:

- Reset the router to default configuration.
- Reinstall network related drivers on the PC in question.
- Change Ethernet ports on both router and PC.
- Assign a static IP-address.

What I would like to avoid doing:

- Reinstall Windows on the PC in question.

I hope someone can help me and other unfortunate people out with this. All suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Does your PC have an IP address when it isn't working?

Comment: Tried a DHCP release/renew when windows boots up for the 2nd time? Can other computers/devices (tablets, phones...) connect, turn off & back on, and connect again to the router?

Comment: What @Paul said. Look at the output of `ipconfig /all` when it doesn't work and compare it to the output of the same command when it does work. Also, try a `tracert` (traceroute) to some known good *IP address*. Google's 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 might be a decent choice for that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling When I have no connection, it is as if the adapter is disabled from the configuration window. So no ip-address or anything. Here is [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/1EE3xH8.png) of the `ipconfig -all` output from when I do have an internet connection, and [here](http://i.imgur.com/aLnNypP.png) is one after computer restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution. To have your computer establish a connection after activating the network adapters *(rebooting)*, you should disable the `DHCP lease` for a specific IP-address and disable any `static IP-address` configurations. After which you should make sure you disable all devices except yours, and reset the router, after which your PC *(device)* will obtain the first ip-address, which will be the preferred IP-address.

This has remedied the issue with my PC not identifying with my home router after computer restart. I didn't think it would be a  simple solution as this, but it was, so I hope this question will help someone in the future.

Comment: I have never had this issue, your answer is a workaround and does not solve the real issue. This is not a normal problem and should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Static IP Address, by configuring the router to issue a specific IP Address to the PC in question, then configuring the PC to use the static IP Address issued by the router.
Not sure if it will work, but by creating direct static communication between the devices might eliminate the confusion during reboots.

Comment: I have done so all this time to avoid any latency and issues with addressing ip-addresses. Here is [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/vL5mNgD.png) of my configuration.